# Prevent Nav bar item from collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**OK, so here's the situation:**

I have a simple, vanilla, `nav nav-tabs` navbar, containing a few items and a rightmost (with `pull-right`) `<li>` item (containing a dropdown).

When the window is resized, the redundant tab items are being hidden, beginning from the rightmost item with the dropdown.

How can I make it "stick" and resist collapsing (or at least, be the last one, and not the first one, to collapse)?

Comment: Resized to what width?

Comment: In bootstrap 3 there is no pull-right or pull-left in the navbar. It's `navbar-right` and `navbar-left`

Comment: @Christina he never said he's using BS3, it isn't in teh tags either, so maybe he's using BS2. Anyways, to the OP, could you please include your code? It's hard to picture your scenario by your sole description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resist collapsing, try this:

Two types are there:

## TYPE 1:

Remove `'collapse navbar-collapse'` class from the collapse div

```
 <div class="" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">  <!--Remove 'collapse navbar-collapse' -->
```

After removing class, there is no need for button, remove toggle `'button'` too.

## [DEMO for Type 1](http://www.bootply.com/k1arJigcTP)

## TYPE 2:

Same as Type 1 , In type one your "resist collapsing" will be satisfied, but view is no good and in the `'sm'` and `'xs'` screen, right content will be displayed in dropdown

For this issue i did some modification:

1. Right conents are shifted to `navbar-header`
2. `navbar-header` width is assigned as `100%`, for right alignment like this

   .navbar-header {
           width: 100%;
       }
3. Then I used `pull-right` for right alignment as per your question, instead of this you can use `navbar-right` also and also added `nav-pills` for avoid wrapping the right content, like this

   `<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills pull-right">`

## [DEMO for Type 2](http://www.bootply.com/7h4OMQPsCQ)